# SQL Server Compact Edition 4 vs the competition (ease of deployment)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I recently am creating a stand alone desktop app, I want to deploy with the least amount of hiccups possible.

I need a RDBMS inside this app. Because of the VS integration I initially decided on using SQL Server Compact Edition (4).

Thinking this should logically copy over relevant DLL's to Bin, and have an application configuration which would contain the connection string pointing to the DB.

Googled a bit, seems it isn't that straightforward.

Which got me thinking, why not use the competition? SQL-Lite comes up on my list, but perhaps there are even better solutions out there.

My question is, is deployment going to end up being a hassle? Would you opt for another RDBMS solution?

EDIT: I just don't have time for a "Oh I get an error message"..... on Windows XP, Windows 7 or 8, and I really don't have much time to test deployment as well as I would like...

Comment: I have used MS ACCESS in many of my small desktop APPs.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I would go for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), deployment can be as simple as a single .DLL together with the .EXE, plus the database file itself, for a grand total of 3 files (again, in the most simplistic form).

For small programs that must run independently of everything, I think it's a good choice. It has a native C API, callable among many languages, plus with the help of additional libraries it can be further used easily in even more.

The downsides would be the lack of integration with VS and the need for an external program to view and manage database files outside your app (SSMS does a great job here for SQL Server).